# Nuget package is using a local version of a dll instead of the on that comes with the package C#

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, arcgis

I am developing a tool for ArcGIS pro 3.1
in the project (.NET 6) I have a nuget package that contains System.ServiceModel.Primitives version 6.0 as one of the references
at the same time, in the bin of ArcGIS pro 3.1, there is a System.ServiceModel.Primitives 4.9.
When I run the code and it gets to loading the module, the code that relies on the package tries to run, and I get this exception

TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.ServiceModel.DuplexChannelFactory`1' from assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Primitives, Version=4.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I tried to do something that I will not do just to see if what I suspect is true, by overwriting the 4.9 to 6.0 in the ArcGIS bin folder, and it passed. Which means for some reason the code is using the 4.9. I reverted that change because that is not a solution and I got the error back.

How do I resolve this ?

I tried using bindingRedirect, I tried loading the dll by it self from the code, and nothing.
I also cant just remove the package and add the references by themselves because I need functions from the package.

RESOLVE ATTEMPT number 1
Use method from linked Question in the comments by adding the reference directly to the project
After adding the reference as its own, nothing changes same error
[image]

Here are all 5 projects, Geospatial, Core, System, ArcGIS and Desktop. Desktop relies on all 4 projects

```
`enter code here`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
        <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
        <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
        <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
        <AssemblyTitle>TX.Geospatial</AssemblyTitle>
        <Product>TX.Geospatial</Product>
        <Copyright>Copyright ©  2023</Copyright>
        <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
        <FileVersion>1.0.0.0</FileVersion>
        <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath> 
        false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>


       <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath> 
       false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
      </PropertyGroup>
     <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' 
      == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
      <OutputPath>..\..\Output\Assemblies\</OutputPath>
        <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
       </PropertyGroup>
       <PropertyGroup Condition="         
       '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
        <OutputPath>..\..\Output\Assemblies\</OutputPath>
     </PropertyGroup>
      <PropertyGroup Condition="'   
        $(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Installer|AnyCPU'">
     <OutputPath>bin\Installer\</OutputPath>
     </PropertyGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include                   
     ="Common.Logging" Version="3.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include=                         
     "Common.Logging.Core" Version="3.4.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="McMaster.NETCore.Plugins" 
        Version="1.4.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" 
       Version="2.22.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" 
        Version="4.7.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="Polly" Version="7.2.4" />
       <PackageReference Include="SE.Geospatial.Desktop.Common" 
      Version="7.1.2" />
        <PackageReference 
      Include="SE.Geospatial.Services.Common.AspNetCore.Tenancy" 
        Version="2.0.0" />
      <PackageReference Include="SE.Geospatial.UserAgent.Sdk" 
      Version="2.0.0">

       </PackageReference>

        <PackageReference 
         Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager"                       
        Version="6.0.1" />
        <PackageReference         
        Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" Version="4.5.0" 
           />
      </ItemGroup>

      <ItemGroup>

        <PackageReference Include= 
        "SE.Geospatial.Editor.Contracts">
         <Version>2.0.0</Version>
        </PackageReference>
         <PackageReference Include=" 
             System.ServiceModel.Primitives" Version="6.0.0"> 
     </PackageReference>
     </ItemGroup>
     <ItemGroup>
       <ProjectReference 
        Include="..\SE.DGS.ArcGIS.Core\ 
        SE.DGS.ArcGIS.Core.csproj" />
      <ProjectReference Include="..\SE.DGS.ArcGIS.Desktop 
          \SE.DGS.ArcGIS.Desktop.csproj" />
     </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Core">
             <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program 
           Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ArcGIS.Core.dll</HintPath>
          </Reference>
         <Reference Include="ArcGIS.CoreHost">
           <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program 
           Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ArcGIS.CoreHost.dll</HintPath>
        </Reference>
         <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Catalog">
          <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program 
         Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\Catalog\ 
          ArcGIS.Desktop.Catalog.dll</HintPath>
           <Private>True</Private>
           </Reference>
<Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Core">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\Core\ArcGIS.Desktop.Core.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.DataGrid.Contrib.Wpf">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ArcGIS.Desktop.DataGrid.Contrib.Wpf.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.DataReviewer">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\DataReviewer\ArcGIS.Desktop.DataReviewer.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Editing">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\Editing\ArcGIS.Desktop.Editing.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Editors.Wpf">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ArcGIS.Desktop.Editors.Wpf.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Extensions">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\DesktopExtensions\ArcGIS.Desktop.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.GeoProcessing">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\GeoProcessing\ArcGIS.Desktop.GeoProcessing.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Layouts">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\Layout\ArcGIS.Desktop.Layouts.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Mapping">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\Mapping\ArcGIS.Desktop.Mapping.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Ribbon.Wpf">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ArcGIS.Desktop.Ribbon.Wpf.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Shared.Wpf">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ArcGIS.Desktop.Shared.Wpf.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.TaskAssistant">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\TaskAssistant\ArcGIS.Desktop.TaskAssistant.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Workflow">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\Workflow\ArcGIS.Desktop.Workflow.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="ESRI.ArcGIS.ItemIndex">
  <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program 
     Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ESRI.ArcGIS.ItemIndex.dll</HintPath>
        </Reference>
       </ItemGroup>
       </Project>
```

Project 2

```
enter code here<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <AssemblyTitle>TX.ArcGIS</AssemblyTitle>
    <Product>TX.ArcGIS</Product>
    <Copyright>Copyright ©  2023</Copyright>
    <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>1.0.0.0</FileVersion>
    <BaseOutputPath/>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>..\..\Output\Assemblies</OutputPath>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>..\..\Output\Assemblies</OutputPath>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.7.0"/>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\SE.DGS.ArcGIS.Core\SE.DGS.ArcGIS.Core.csproj"/>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Core">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ArcGIS.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.CoreHost">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ArcGIS.CoreHost.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Catalog">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\Catalog\ArcGIS.Desktop.Catalog.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Core">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\Core\ArcGIS.Desktop.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.DataGrid.Contrib.Wpf">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ArcGIS.Desktop.DataGrid.Contrib.Wpf.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.DataReviewer">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\DataReviewer\ArcGIS.Desktop.DataReviewer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Editing">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\Editing\ArcGIS.Desktop.Editing.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Editors.Wpf">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ArcGIS.Desktop.Editors.Wpf.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Extensions">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\DesktopExtensions\ArcGIS.Desktop.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.GeoProcessing">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\GeoProcessing\ArcGIS.Desktop.GeoProcessing.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Layouts">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\Layout\ArcGIS.Desktop.Layouts.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Mapping">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\Mapping\ArcGIS.Desktop.Mapping.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Ribbon.Wpf">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ArcGIS.Desktop.Ribbon.Wpf.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Shared.Wpf">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ArcGIS.Desktop.Shared.Wpf.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.TaskAssistant">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\TaskAssistant\ArcGIS.Desktop.TaskAssistant.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Workflow">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\Workflow\ArcGIS.Desktop.Workflow.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ESRI.ArcGIS.ItemIndex">
        <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ESRI.ArcGIS.ItemIndex.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Project>
```

Project 3 TT.System

```
enter code hereProject Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

                <PropertyGroup>
                <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;Installer</Configurations>
<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
<AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
 <PropertyGroup 
 Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
<OutputPath>..\..\Output\Assemblies\</OutputPath>
<PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
     </PropertyGroup>
       <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
         <OutputPath>..\..\Output\Assemblies\</OutputPath>
        </PropertyGroup>
       <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="SE.DGS.System" Version="2.3.1"/>
        <PackageReference Include="SE.DGS.System.Configuration" Version="3.0.0"/>
    </ItemGroup>
   </Project>
```

Project 4

```
enter code here<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
 <PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFrameworks>net6.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
  <GeneratePackageOnBuild>false</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
  <PackageId>$(AssemblyName)_31</PackageId>
   <Title>SE DGS ArcGIS Pro Core 3.1 SDK Extensions</Title>
   <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
 
    <Description>A reusable library extending ArcGIS.Core. 
    </Description>
    <Copyright>2023</Copyright>

    <PackageTags>arcgis core</PackageTags>
    <IncludeSymbols>False</IncludeSymbols>
    <SymbolPackageFormat>symbols.nupkg</SymbolPackageFormat



    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false 
    </AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>





     <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false
     </AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
     </PropertyGroup>
     <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)
      |$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
      <OutputPath>..\..\Output\Assemblies</OutputPath>
      <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
     </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$ 
    (Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <OutputPath>..\..\Output\Assemblies</OutputPath>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
  <Folder Include="GeometryHelper\" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="..\README.md">
    <Pack>True</Pack>
    <PackagePath>\</PackagePath>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  <PackageReference Include="SE.DGS.System" Version="2.3.1" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Core">
    <HintPath>..\..\..\..\..\..\..\Program Files\ 
      ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ArcGIS.Core.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
 </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Finally Desktop project where the add in runs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
      <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
     <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath> 
     false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies> 
     true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath> 
     false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <NoWarn>CA1416</NoWarn>
    <OutputPath>..\..\Output\Assemblies</OutputPath>
    <PackageOutputPath>..\..\Output\Assemblies</PackageOutputPath>
   </PropertyGroup>

   <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Config.daml"/>
    <Content Include="Images\AddInDesktop16.png"/>
    <Content Include="Images\AddInDesktop32.png"/>
    <Content Include="DarkImages\AddInDesktop16.png"/>
    <Content Include="DarkImages\AddInDesktop32.png"/>
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="TX.Core" Version="1.1.0"/>

   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>

       <ProjectReference Include="..\TX.ArcGIS\TX.ArcGIS.csproj"/>
       <ProjectReference 
        Include="..\TX.Geospatial\TX.Geospatial.csproj"/>
       <ProjectReference Include="..\TX.System\TX.System.csproj"/>
       <ProjectReference 
       Include="..\SE.DGS.ArcGIS.Core\SE.DGS.ArcGIS.Core.csproj"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
       <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework">
           <HintPath>C:\Program 
       Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ArcGIS.Desktop.Framework.dll 
           </HintPath>
           <CopyLocal>False</CopyLocal>
           <Private>False</Private>
       </Reference>
       <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Core">
           <HintPath>C:\Program 
             Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ArcGIS.Core.dll                                      
           </HintPath>
           <CopyLocal>False</CopyLocal>
           <Private>False</Private>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Core">
           <HintPath>C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions 
            \Core\ArcGIS.Desktop.Core.dll</HintPath>
           <CopyLocal>False</CopyLocal>
           <Private>False</Private>
        </Reference>
       <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Mapping">
             <HintPath>C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions 
        \Mapping\ArcGIS.Desktop.Mapping.dll</HintPath>
        <CopyLocal>False</CopyLocal>
        <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Catalog">
        <HintPath>C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\ 
         Catalog\ArcGIS.Desktop.Catalog.dll</HintPath>
        <CopyLocal>False</CopyLocal>
        <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Editing">
        <HintPath>C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\Editing\ 
         ArcGIS.Desktop.Editing.dll</HintPath>
        <CopyLocal>False</CopyLocal>
        <Private>False</Private>
       </Reference>
        <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Extensions">
        <HintPath>C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions 
        \DesktopExtensions\ArcGIS.Desktop.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
        <CopyLocal>False</CopyLocal>
        <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
       <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.GeoProcessing">
        <HintPath>C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\ 
         GeoProcessing\ArcGIS.Desktop.GeoProcessing.dll</HintPath>
        <CopyLocal>False</CopyLocal>
        <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Layouts">
        <HintPath>C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Extensions\ 
         Layout\ArcGIS.Desktop.Layouts.dll</HintPath>
        <CopyLocal>False</CopyLocal>
        <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Shared.Wpf">
        <HintPath>C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ 
         ArcGIS.Desktop.Shared.Wpf.dll</HintPath>
        <CopyLocal>False</CopyLocal>
        <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Ribbon.Wpf">
        <HintPath>C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ 
         ArcGIS.Desktop.Ribbon.Wpf.dll</HintPath>
        <CopyLocal>False</CopyLocal>
        <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.DataGrid.Contrib.Wpf">
        <HintPath>C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ 
         ArcGIS.Desktop.DataGrid.Contrib.Wpf.dll</HintPath>
        <CopyLocal>False</CopyLocal>
        <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ArcGIS.Desktop.Resources">
        <HintPath>C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ 
         ArcGIS.Desktop.Resources.dll</HintPath>
        <CopyLocal>False</CopyLocal>
        <Private>False</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="ESRI.ArcGIS.ItemIndex">
        <HintPath>C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\ 
         ESRI.ArcGIS.ItemIndex.dll</HintPath>
        <CopyLocal>False</CopyLocal>
        <Private>False</Private>
        </Reference>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Import Project="C:\Program 
    Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Esri.ProApp.SDK.Desktop.targets" 
     Condition="Exists('C:\Program 
     Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Esri.ProApp.SDK.Desktop.targets') AND 
    !Exists('Esri.ArcGISPro.Extensions.targets')"/>
   </Project>
```

Comment: This does not resolve it, I referenced the package in the project file which adds it separately as it's own, and I still get the same error.

Comment: Do you have a link to a sample source project?

Comment: No but if you are looking for something specific I can paste it in the question. for example do you want to see the project file ? the app.config file ? I'll be happy to post those up

Comment: the way to debug anything in msbuild is using https://msbuildlog.com. it takes some experience to get good, but if you search for the dll name, you'll be able to see where different versions of the dll are coming from, and hopefully figure out why it's selecting the version that it is.

Comment: And even if your repo is private, you can still [create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by deleting all the code files, remove all package references to packages not on nuget.org, and delete all projects that aren't relevant. Rename the remaining projects if necessary. Even though I work on NuGet, I can't guess why your project is doing this. We need the msbuild binlog to investigate.

Comment: If both libs work with 6.0, then referencing the 6.0 as a top-level dependency is the correct solution. Make sure to rebuild after adding the reference to regenerate the `deps.json` file. In some cases, just hitting F5 in VS will still try to load an old reference.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by if "If both libs work with 6.0" ArcGIS Pro Bin contains version 4.9. The project relies on 6.0, but the project is not loading 6.0, it is loading from 4.9 for some reason.

Comment: and the project needs 6.0 to run, not 4.9

Comment: Without seeing your entire csproj it is impossible. Enable warnings as errors and see something like "Dependency specified was X but ended up with Y", it is probably some other 3rd party or your library which references this library.

Comment: I just posted all 5 projects, Desktop project relies on the 4 projects above of it.

Comment: 1. Try deleting the local copy of the 4.9 version dll
2. Check platform/architecture (arm/intel, x86/x64) of the project and the 6.0 version dll and ensure they match.
3. Try forcing Required Framework version in app.config

Comment: For one I cant do that, it is part of the Bin folder for ArcGIS pro 3.1 I will not modify this. 2. I already checked and they match as far as I can tell. How do I do 3 ?? how do I force required version in the app.config ?

Comment: Try referencing `System.ServiceModel.Primitives v6.0.0` in your desktop project. If it still loads an old version (4.9), go to the output folder folder and check the `.deps.json` file. Look for the problematic package version and travel up the tree until you find who brings the wrong version.

Comment: It looks like you are using the same folder in the `OutputPath` for all projects. Is that correct? I think one of the projects that reference 4.9 is built after the project that references 6.0 and overrides the DLL in the `OutputPath`. Referencing the package in the Desktop project should solve it because it's built last.

Comment: .deps.json the correct version is loaded which 6.0, and I already  know where the 4.9 is, it is in the bin folder or arcgis pro. The software I am writing an add in for. Also NON of the projects is referencing 4.9, not in any package and version 6.0 is what's being written to the output location

Comment: Two suggestions: 1. Add some code to load the first dll as soon as possible in the application. 2. Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/681802/two-sub-library-projects-in-one-solution-use-same

Comment: I tried suggestion one, loading the dll as soon as the add in is initialized, same result.

Comment: I tried suggestion number 2, and added the config file, but also no good.